# Почему происходит бесконечная переадресация с http на https и обратно?

Tags: php, nginx, веб-сервер, https, веб-служба

Я установил сертификат с помощью https://letsencrypt.org/.

Но при заходе на сайт происходит бесконечная переадресация с http на https и обратно, ошибка "Сайт stasenok.com выполнил переадресацию слишком много раз." "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS".

В чем может быть проблема, в настройках сервера плохо разбираюсь.

**Код моего конфига домена:**

```
server {
server_name stasenok.com;

listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/stasenok.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/stasenok.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

server_tokens off;
keepalive_timeout 70;

index index.php index.html;
root /var/www/stasenok.com/data;    
include /etc/nginx/global_server.conf;

location / {
    auth_basic           "closed site";
    auth_basic_user_file /var/www/.htpasswd;
    include /etc/nginx/bad_bots.conf; //Закомментирована строка
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    include fastcgi_params;}}


server {
server_name stasenok.com;

listen 80;
access_log  off;
error_log off;
rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$1 permanent;}
```

**Конфиг файла global_server:**

```
location ~* \.(xml|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|woff|otf|ttf|eot|svg|txt|pdf|docx?|xlsx?|css|js)$ {
    access_log off;
    error_log off;
    log_not_found off;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;}


if ($host ~* www\.(.*)) {
        set $host_without_www $1;
        rewrite ^(.*)$ https://$host_without_www$1 permanent;
}
```

Comment: кмк вторая запись server вообще не нужна. тем более что в ней редирект на саму себя

Comment: и на будущее. добавляйте в вопрос текст а не картинки

Comment: Теперь вовсе не работает, пишет приветствие nginx

Comment: отредактируйте вопрос и разместите конфигурацию в виде текста. и добавьте содержимое global_server.conf

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Прикрепил код двух файлов.

Comment: В данном коде нет таких редиректов. Я на 99% уверен, что редирект приходит из PHP

Comment: Либо там рядом лежит ещё один серверный конфиг.

Comment: Серверный конфиг это nginx.conf? Или который в папке conf.d, под названием default.conf

Comment: И как может редирект приходит из php?

Comment: В общем включайте дебаг-логи и разбирайтесь.  И да, конечно PHP тоже может отправлять редиректы.